Delphi 5 program throws error 0xC0000006 on Windows RDS 2019
My client has run our software written with Delphi 5 on Windows RDS Server 2008 for several years without any problems. The program is stored on the server and all users open it via network. We use SQLServer and connect to it via ODBC and BDE.
Now he upgraded to RDS Server 2019 and since then, from time to time, the error 0xC0000006 is thrown when a user starts the program.
We activated compatibility mode for Windows 7/8/Vista, and in this mode the error occurs not when starting the program, but during runtime. As soon as 1 user gets the error, all other users cannot work anymore and must restart their programs.
I searched for a solution and, in most cases, the suggestion was to use a compiler flag ($SetPeFlags) to force Windows to load the program completely in memory. Unfortunately, this flag isn't supported in Delphi 5.
Is there another way to either tell Delphi or the Windows server to load the program completely in memory?

You could set the PE flag with a hex editor.

Short answer - either use Microsoft's editbin  or similar tool to update the PE flags after building the exe, or else have the users run the exe on their local machines instead of over the network.
